# How to Send Sequence to Web Gene Prediction Server in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, web, bioinformatics

I am currently doing some projects about 'ab initio gene prediction' programs.
I found some interesting web gene prediction servers such as 'FGENESH' and 'GenScan'.
Url Below:
http://linux1.softberry.com/berry.phtml?topic=fgenesh&group=programs&subgroup=gfind

What I want to ask you is how I can send DNA sequence file in my computer through python script, not using web browser. Also, I want to know how to parse the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The raw way for your problem is to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) (kind of simulates the browser). And then for parsing XML/HTML-results, you probably want to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), which allows you to get the XML-structure in a composited object-oriented format, from where you can access text and attributes. There are dozens of examples for usage of both libraries on the web.

However, these web-service typically have some more programmer-friendly API for processing requests, which you can use most easily access with [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html). I guess there are many example scripts already doing stuff with PDB (quick googling brought [this one](http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_protein.html)) or similar, so these might be good starting points.